# ¿Cómo se trata el guión en el orden alfabético?

Tags: ortografía, orden-de-palabras, alfabeto

La ordenación alfabética de las palabras se realiza mediante unas sencillas reglas [Portal Educativo - orden alfabético](https://www.portaleducativo.net/segundo-basico/73/Orden-alfabetico):

> Ordenar palabras es determinar su ubicación, de acuerdo al orden de las letras en el alfabeto. Para ello debes tener en cuenta los siguientes elementos:
>
> La primera letra de cada palabra, por ejemplo:
>
> Buque - Carabinero - Azúcar
>
> Se deben colocar en el siguiente orden:
> Azúcar, porque empieza con A
> Buque, Por que [sic] comienza con B
> Carabinero, Porque [sic] comienza con C
>
> Si se repite la primera letra, nos fijaremos en la segunda, que también debe seguir el orden de las letras del alfabeto.
>
> Leamos este ejemplo:
> Farol - Educación - Economía - Foca -  Empezar:
> Al ordenar estas palabras por la primera letra, obtenemos dos grupos: el de las que comienzan por **e**, y el de las que empiezan con **f**. Se ponen primero las que empiezan por **e**, y entre estas tendremos que fijarnos en la segunda letra.
>
> Las segundas letras son **c**, **m** y **d**. Siguiendo el orden del alfabeto, va primero la **c**, sigue la **d** y luego la **m**. Entonces el orden correcto es el siguiente:
>
> Economía - Educación - Empezar - Farol - Foca
>
> Si las dos primeras letras son iguales, deberás tomar en cuenta la tercera letra y así sucesivamente.
>
> Por ejemplo:
>
> Ducha - Dudar - Dulce

El problema es cuando en la palabra aparecen símbolos que **no son letras**, como el guión. Por ejemplo [agar-agar](https://dle.rae.es/agar-agar), [chupa-chup](https://dle.rae.es/chupa-chup) [hula-hula](https://dle.rae.es/hula-hula), [*foie-gras*](https://dle.rae.es/foie-gras), etc.

Por poner un caso concreto, si tenemos que ordenar alfabéticamente las palabras **moro**, **moros**, **mortal**, **morocho** , el orden correcto es moro -> morocho -> moros -> mortal. Pero si se añade [**moro-moro**](https://dle.rae.es/moro-moro) a la lista ¿dónde iría?
¿Inmediatamente después de moro porque el guión va antes que la "a"?
¿Entre morocho y moro, porque el guión no se considera y la segunda "m" de moro-moro van despues de la "c" de morocho pero antes que la segunda "o" de moro?
¿Entre moros y mortal porque el guión va después de la "z"?

No encuentro ninguna norma en [Principales novedades de la última edición de la Ortografía de la lengua española (2010)](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Principales_novedades_de_la_Ortografia_de_la_lengua_espanola.pdf).

¿Cómo se ordenan alfabéticamente las palabras que contienen un guión?

Answer (score 4):

Pues según la versión de 1992 del DLE, la última que se puede consultar en el NTLLE (y de la que por tanto podemos ver su versión el papel), diría que lo que hace es hacer como si el guion no existiera. Para demostrarlo, expongo a continuación un par de ejemplos del orden en el que introduce las palabras en el listado:

- morojo > moro-moro > morón (la *j* antes que la *m* y esta antes que la *n*)
- agarabatado > agar-agar > agarbado (esta palabra aparece también en el Alemany y Bolufer de 1917 y sigue el mismo criterio de hacer como que el guion no existiera para establecer el orden)

Esta regla viene de antiguo, por ejemplo en el Terreros y Pando de 1786 veo que se usa la misma norma y establece el orden *chupadúra* > *chupa-flores* > *chupar* (la *d* antes que la *f* y esta antes que la *p*). Y en el *Autoridades*, tomo S-Z de 1739, se establece el orden *vicecanciller* > *vice-dios* > *vicepreposito* (la *c* antes que la *d* y esta antes que la *p*).

Se ve por tanto que el guion no entra en el orden alfabético y se ignora completamente a la hora de ordenar las palabras.

Comment: Excelente respuesta; nada que agregar. Pero no pude evitar comentar que me parece maravillosa la existencia del término vice-dios en un libro de 1739.

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez sí, a mí también me llamó mucho la atención que se usara _vice-dios_ para referirse al Papa. Grandioso.